# Time range selector with resize handles in Vega

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vega

The vega documentation mentions selection interactions like these: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#scale-domains

[image]

It's basically a master/detail view where the whole data is shown below and can be selected for the detailed view above.

What i'd like to have is that the selection has resize handlers on both sides. An example would be how Highstock handles this: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

[image]

Is there way to achieve this in vega?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a ready solution, but you can take a look at the Vega-Lite spec from the [Falcon](https://github.com/uwdata/falcon) project. If you [go to histogram.ts](https://github.com/uwdata/falcon/blob/master/src/views/histogram.ts#L236-L345) and search for *grabber*, you will see the specification that might be useful to you. You can also play around with the [interactive demo](https://uwdata.github.io/falcon/flights/).